# Missing grant_type parameter in postman

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, postman

I am using  [Brightspace](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/index.html) API.

I am using the `post` method and the URL is `https://auth.brightspace.com/core/connect/token`

Reference link [here](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/oauth2.html?highlight=core%20connect%20token)

I have all the below details

```
Auth URL,
Access Token URL,
Client Id,
Client Secret,
Scope,
```

`Grant Type`, I have selected the `Authorization code` option.

In header, `Content-Type` is also `application/json`

[image]

Now, When I clicked on send button then I am getting an error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing \"grant_type\" parameter"
}
```

Any idea I am getting this error?

Comment: Grant types are not specific to this provider, it is used through [any oAuth 2.0 flow](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/). You're likely needing an `authorization_code`

Comment: @Jaquarh, I am new to API. Any idea where I can get the authorization_code? do I need to add somewhere? I have Brightspace authentication username and password

Comment: Grant Type I have selected password credentials and added the username and password but still same issue

Comment: The link in your OP, point #2, literally tells you to `Use the Authorization Code Grant workflow defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification` as I just specified. "Username and password" is not oAuth 2.0....... You need to register your app and use your keys. Follow the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html) reference

Comment: @Jaquarh, yes I am using key only not username and password and I have selected Authorization code option from dropdown for Grant typ. But not sure why I am getting error

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly call POST method for  response type "Code"
due to after POST call, Keycloak (IdP Server) redirect to registered URL (redirect_uri) for Login activity.
Luckily, In the Postman can do it by "Get New Token" in OAuto 2.0 mode.

I have no D2L Brightspace account's client ID /secret so I can't demo how to that but I captured image from It's video tutorial.

You can do it with your client ID /secret.
Steps

1. Set **environment variable** set in Postman (click right the top area's icon)
   clientid, clientsecret with your values and oauth2scope(content:*.*)
   [image]
2. **Start "Get New Token"**
   select "Authorization" tab, select "OAuth 2.0" type, "Request Headers" and click the "Get New Access Token" in Request ( in Collection also possible)
   [image]
3. **Set the fields for each parameter**

Enter 3 URLS from 1~3

Enter 3 environment variable with {{ variable name here }} from 4~6

Click the "Request Token" it will get access token.
[image]
more detail information in [here](https://community.brightspace.com/s/article/Using-Postman-with-the-Brightspace-API), [video](https://github.com/Brightspace/Postman-Collections/blob/main/1%20-%20Start%20Here%20-%20GetInitialToken/Get%20Initial%20Tokens.mp4) and [Postman collection](https://github.com/Brightspace/Postman-Collections)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am new to API.   any idea where I can get the access token code? SS here https://i.ibb.co/3WdxXHm/Screenshot-2022-07-28-at-11-03-05-auth-My-Workspace.png   Also, How to change the callback URL? because I am not able to edit https://i.ibb.co/X5SQ3Lb/Screenshot-2022-07-28-at-11-05-40-auth-My-Workspace.png

Comment: I have Access Token Lifetime(seconds):3600

Comment: @user9437856, congratulation, can you give me thumb's up?
The callback URL can update/add in your  **brightspace** account's setting page.
You can see all more API call (line refresh token , and others) in [Postman collection](https://github.com/Brightspace/Postman-Collections)

Comment: But my issue is not solved yet. I am still getting the same error. After adding all the information and click on Get New token access then next tab open and showing error "invalid_request"

Comment: It is little complicate, I would like to reproduce it then I will update my steps.
Can your send your client ID / secret, and redirect URL  to my e-mail(benchvue101@gmail.com)?
Later you can revoke(update secret) after got how to get access token by single POST.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t share that details. Do you have any video or any documentation where I can learn?

Comment: OK, this [web site](https://hmh.engineering/how-to-get-oauth-access-token-and-retrieve-data-from-google-apis-using-postman-9a95ffe030ae) shows the code flow. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for sharing the doc link, i have tried but i am not getting the access token. it's opening the new tab but showing invalid requests.

Comment: I said it is little complicate to get access code for "code" flow. Also each IdP provider variation.  I try to member into brightspace but it charged a price. If you willing to really want to know makes temporary client ID /secret then let me know. I can do it try for you.

Comment: do you have any link or code to connect OAuth 2.0 using PHP and cURL.

Comment: I have no experience PHP but OAuth2.0 with Postman. how to get OAuto2.0 token?[This URL worked](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2) and [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/oauth-2-0-authorization-with-postman/). I tested my imgur account and can get access token and get the image list.     [Get image call](https://api.imgur.com/3/account/me/images)  this result "{
    "data": [],
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
}"